# Why do we have to specifically define a branch of the complex square root function?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, radicals

If $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$.

Isn't this a well defined function on the whole complex plane?

Why do we need to define this as the function $\mathbb C \setminus \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \le 0\} \to \{re^{i\theta} \mid -\pi < \theta < \pi\}$?

Comment: So as $1=1e^{i2\pi}$ then $\sqrt1=\sqrt1e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's "well-defined" if you, for every $z$, pick some $\theta_z$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\theta_z}$, but the function above won't be continuous.

Let $x\in (-\infty,0)$ and consider $x+i\varepsilon$ and $x-i\varepsilon$. The square-root you seem to define of the first thing tends to $i\sqrt{|x|}$ as $\varepsilon\to 0,$ while the second one tends to $-i\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: So basically, this comes down to continuity of an argument function: If you choose an argument, say at $1$ and then vary the argument continuously in a circle, as you return to $1$, the natural choice of argument is $2\pi$ greater (or smaller in case you traversed the circle clockwise).

Comment: Can we always define a branch of $\sqrt{z}$ by just deleting a ray. For example, what if we define the square root as $\mathbb C \setminus \{re^{i\theta} \mid \theta \ne \pi/2\} \to \{re^{i\theta} \mid -\frac{3\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}\}$?

Comment: You can always define a holomorphic choice of square-root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{rz\}_{r\geq 0}$ for any $z\neq 0$, because it's possible to define a continuous argument function. It's a general statement that on a simply connected, open domain $U$ , you can define a holomorphic squareroot of any holomorphic function which never vanishes - in this case, it's the identity.

Comment: So, what does it mean that square root has only two branches. It seems it has infinitely many branches.

Comment: On a GIVEN domain, it only has two: If I tell you what the value of the holomorphic squareroot at a point is (and there you only have a choice of sign), you know its value anywhere (simply for reasons of continuity!).

Answer (score 0):

So is $\sqrt {-1}$ equal to $i$ or $-i?$